# Calculating last Campaign response for each sales opportunity

Tags: sql

I have the following tables: Opportunity, Account, Contact, CampaignMember and Campaign.

[image: erd]

For each Opportunity, I want to assemble a table using SQL to figure out: **what was the last Campaign response prior to the Opportunity being created?** We call this the "Last Touch" Campaign.

To figure this out, we must start with an Opportunity, look at the related Account, look at all of the Contacts related to this Account and return the CampaignMember for this Account with the **most recent** ResponseDate that is **before** the Opportunity.CreatedDate.

The output should have 3 columns: Opportunity ID, Last Touch Campaign Id, and Last Touch Campaign Type.

Example:
[image: erd-example]

For Opportunity ID 1, CampaignMember ID 3 has the most recent Response Date that is also *before* the Opportunity CreatedDate.

For Opportunity ID 2, CampaignMember ID 4 has the most recent Response Date that is before the Opportunity Created Date. We must disregard the Campaign Member responses that occurred after the Opportunity was created.

In our example, it just so happens that the same Campaign was the "Last Touch" prior to an Opportunity being created.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your table scheme. An ascii view or the table descriptors would make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: It's always appreciated less literature and more examples focusing on exactly what's your problem

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki I've added an ERD diagram, does this help?

Comment: @JaimeDrq thank you for the feedback, I've added an example

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support WIndowed Aggregates like `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: really better now!

Comment: @dnoeth MS SQL Server

Comment: Add a `ROW_NUMBER` to your existing Select, `partition by opportunity.id order by CampaignMember.ResponseDate DESC) as rn`, wrap it in a CTE or Derived Table and then filter using `WHERE rn = 1`

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly but seems to work (tested on a db fiddle - changed names, please correct it to your base).

```
select dt.id, campaign.id as LastTouchId, campaign.type as LastTouchType from (
    select opportunity.id, max(ct.responsedate) as responsedate from opportunity
        left join account on account.id = opportunity.account_id
        left join (select contact.account_id, campaignmember.responsedate from
        contact inner join campaignmember on campaignmember.id = contact.campaignmember_id) 
        as ct on ct.account_id = account.id and ct.responsedate < opportunity.createddate
        group by opportunity.id) as dt
    inner join account on account.id = dt.id
    inner join contact on contact.account_id = account.id
    inner join campaignmember on campaignmember.id = contact.campaignmember_id and 
    campaignmember.responsedate = dt.responsedate
    inner join campaign on campaign.id = campaignmember.campaign_id
```

Comment: I've modified this to use my table/column names, but it returns 0 rows. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a36735373924f347b1815b9d462a4cde

Comment: please check the inner queries result first. I've probably mistaken the tables relationship.